# Need to setup Printer Server

Tags: server

I need to set up a Printer server on Ubuntu Server where I need to install the printer in windows client computers as well.

My printer models what I have are network printers (Konica Minolta C284e, Xerox C8045 & Xerox B8045 )

Please kindly help me how can I configure the server in ubuntu.

I am using a workgroup.

Comment: Set up your printers on the server with CUPS (`http://localhost:631`), enable printer sharing.

Comment: Can you please guide me on how to configure cups

Comment: No, I  can't.  It's contrary to the philosophy of AskUbuntu. Begin with `man -k cups` (and read some of the listed pages), and browse to `http://localhost:631/admin`, `http://localhost:631/ help`.